# Gnuplot - change background color

Tags: linux, svg, gnuplot

I used gnuplot to create a graph on linux. The script creates a svg file, but its background has black and white squares. How can I create a white and clear background? The script that I used is below :

```
set terminal svg enhanced size 1000 1000 fname "Times" fsize 36
set   autoscale 
set output "plot.svg"
set title "A simple plot of x^2 vs. x"
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
plot "./data.dat" using 1:2 title ""
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Those black and white squares are inserted by your viewer program, and indicate that you actually have no background. To get a white background, use the `background` terminal option:

```
set terminal svg enhanced background rgb 'white'
```

If your gnuplot version doesn't yet support this option, you can place a full-canvas rectangle behind the plot

```
set object rectangle from screen 0,0 to screen 1,1 behind fillcolor rgb 'white' fillstyle solid noborder
...
plot x
```

Comment: Thank you, second option was a life saver.

Comment: @djhaskin987 ... even the first, you can put in your scripts `set terminal GNUTERM background rgb 'white' ` or whatever... :)

Comment: If you use "graph 0,0" instead of "screen 0,0" you could have multiple different background in case of multiplot (remember to "unset object OBJECTNAME" before the next subplot)